# Python: Reading and writing to a .rps file with 'r+b'

Tags: python

I have created a Rock, Paper, Scissors game that takes user input and plays the game versus the computer and saves the results.

The user is displayed a list of choices, the final choice being to quit the game which will then save their wins, losses and ties to an .rps file. In the actual game, you can view the statistics and so when you quit the game, I am using a pickle dump to add them to the file. The .rps file output should be as follows:

```
user_name
wins:
losses:
ties:
```

The code that I have for this section is:

```
try:
    user = self.name
    rps = ('.rps')
    file = user + rps
    save_file = open(file, 'r+b')
    pickle.dump(user, save_file)
    user_wins = self.wins
    pickle.dump(user_wins, save_file)
    user_losses = self.losses
    pickle.dump(user_losses, save_file)
    user_ties = self.ties
    pickle.dump(user_ties, save_file)
    save_file.close()
    print(self.name, ' , your game has been saved.', sep='')
    self.play = False

except Exception as err:
    print('Sorry ', self.name, ', the game could not be saved.')
    print(err)
    self.play = False
```

I am using classes for practice so this is just a portion of the code, but this is the only part that is not working. I get a 'No such file or directory exists' error every time I try to quit the program and save the results. I already tested the path to make sure it should be creating the file in the correct directory and it is, but I'm not sure why it doesn't create the file if it doesn't already exist. I thought that's what using 'r+b' does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a+b, not r+b

> rb+
>
> Opens a file for both reading and writing in binary format. The file pointer placed at the beginning of the file.
>
> ab+
>
> Opens a file for both appending and reading in binary format. The file pointer is at the end of the file if the file exists. The file opens in the append mode. If the file does not exist, it creates a new file for reading and writing.

Source: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm

Note that the file pointer will be at the end of file if there is any text already there. If you want to open the file using rb+, use a helper method to check if the file exists first, and if the file doesn't exist, create it.

```
def createFileIfNotExists(filePath):
     open(filePath, 'ab+')
     close(filePath)
     return
```

Note my function is inefficient I'd suggest looking for a more elegant solution if you want to go that route.

Comment: I want the file pointer to be at the beginning though. Every time the file is opened, it should just overwrite what is already in it because there will be new values that have to replace the old ones. But why isn't the file being created in the first place?

Comment: You want `wb+

Opens a file for both writing and reading in binary format. Overwrites the existing file if the file exists. If the file does not exist, creates a new file for reading and writing.` then. Read the source link I sent you. The file isn't being created in the first place because r+b doesn't create the file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Wow. Can't believe I missed that. Now I feel dumb! Appreciate it!